# Does Visual Studio Community 2017 require sign in with microsoft account?

Tags: c#, windows

The question pretty much is self explanatory. I just want to know if I can use Visual Studio without signing into my Microsoft account.

Comment: You should sign in to unlock the Visual Studio Community Edition instead of being limited to the trial period of 30 days, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457348.aspx#Anchor_0

Answer (score 9):

The community edition is free for 30 days. After that you'll have to sign in/create an account.

Comment: To clarify this answer a bit: The community edition is still free after those 30 days.  The account can be an unpaid account.

Comment: I don't see a point why they have made sign in mandatory. In fact, I do not see a point in keeping myself signed into some system just to use Visual Studio.

Comment: Well, if you have to sign in, then it is not "free" - you're paying for it with your personal information, which Microsoft will likely sell elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

No, if you just want to try it for 30 days. but later on you have to sign-in with you Microsoft account to use it further.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft VS Community For individuals :

> Any individual developer can use Visual Studio Community to create their own free or paid apps.

VS Community Free just in 30 Days after that you'll have to Sign in.

Comment: You make it sound as if tese were two different products..?